# Mapstruct: Auto-increment a object variable in a list of objects

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have some POJOs like this:

```
@Data
public class A {
    List<B> bList;
}

@Data
public class B {
    int id;
    int x;
}

@Data
public class C {
    List<D> dList;
}

@Data
public class D {
    int x;
}
```

Now I want to map class C to class A using MapStruct such that value of id in bList in class A is auto incremented. I am using Mapstruct 1.1.0.Final.

For mapping `List<D>` to `List<B>`, I can define a mapper for `class B` and `class D` and the POJOs would be automatically mapped, but couldn't find a way where I can map POJOs along with auto increment on a field.

My POJO is very much big. Is there a way in Map Struct for auto-incrementing variables in a list?

Comment: Can you provide some more information. When do you want to do an auto increment? After the mapping between `c` and `A` or after the mapping of `B` to `D`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ideally, it should be while mapping D to B. I have found two solutions for this: using a global thread local variable in the abstract class and writing expression like `java("getAndIncrement(counter)")`, where `getAndIncrement` is a method to get and increment thread local variable ( not a good solution though, but since I had huge POJOs, so mapping manually would be a time consuming Task ). Second solution: using `@AfterMapping` annotation. After C is mapped to A, manually autoincrement id values in B list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to do this with 1.1.0.Final and one more option with 1.2.0.Beta2.

**First option while mapping `D` to `B`**

You can use `@AfterMapping` between `D` and `B` and use a `ThreadLocal` there.

```
public class AutoIncrementorThreadLocal {

    @AfterMapping
    public /*static*/ void autoIncrementId(D source, @MappingTarget B target) {
        //here you use the ThreadLocal and do something like getAndIncrement
    }
}
```

In your mapper you will have to say that you are using the `AutoIncrementorThreadLocal`. Also the method can be static, MapStruct can invoke static methods as well.

**Second option while mapping `C` to `A`**

```
public class AutoIncrementorBulk {

    @AfterMapping
    public /*static*/ void autoIncrementId(C source, @MappingTarget A target) {
        //here you iterate the list and increment the ids
    }
}
```

In your mapper you will have to say that you are using the `AutoIncrementorBulk`. Also the method can be static, MapStruct can invoke static methods as well.

**Third option with 1.2.0.Beta2**

You can use the new `@Context` and have `@AfterMapping` on it.

```
public class AutoIncrementorContext {

    private int counter = 0;
    @AfterMapping
    public void autoIncrementId(D source, @MappingTarget B target) {
        //here you use your counter, because you are only using this instance during one mapping
    }
}
```

Your Mapper will need to look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    C map(A source, @Context AutoIncrementorContext context);

    D map(B source, @Context AutoIncrementorContext context);
}
```

When you are going to call your mapper you will need to call it like:

`myMapper.map(a, new AutoIncrementorContext());`

The first and third approaches are similar with the only difference that you don't have to use `ThreadLocal`(s) with the third approach.

Comment: thanks for the reply. In first option can't we use local variable instead of thread locals, as we are writing the method body? Also to avoid writing body, we can use a thread local class level variable and use expression like `java("getAndIncrement(counter)")` where `getAndIncrement` method increments the counter ( a thread local variable ).

Comment: From what I understood in your question you want `List<B>` in `A` to have some auto increment ID. The first option method will be called when mapping any `D` into `B`, so you can't really use local variables, what ID will you use? You will always have one object to increment on?

Comment: For your second part. Yes you can use an abstract class with a thread local class level variable and increment the counter like that. However, I prefer to avoid using expression and use `@AfterMapping` and `@Context`. I prefer not using `ThreadLocal` if possible. I can update the answer with a class variable `ThreadLocal` if you think it's worth it